# Play Framework - Store Information About Current Request

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

In my play framework 2 application I'd like to have a log message with the request, response, and some details about the response - such as the number of search results returned from an external web call.

What I have now is a filter like this:

```
object AccessLog extends Filter {
  import play.api.mvc._
  import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits._

  def apply(next: RequestHeader => Future[SimpleResult])(request: RequestHeader): Future[SimpleResult] = {
    val result = next(request)
    result map { r =>
      play.Logger.info(s"Request: ${request.uri} - Response: ${r.header.status}")
    }
    result
  }
}
```

At the point of logging, I've alread converted my classes into json, so it seems wasteful to  parse the json back into objects so I can log information about it.

Is it possible to compute the number of search results earlier in the request pipeline, maybe into a dictionary, and pull them out when I log the message here?

I was looking at flash, but don't want the values to be sent out in a cookie at any cost. Maybe I can clear the flash instead. Buf if there's a more suitable way I'd like to see that.

This is part of a read-only API that does not involve user accounts or sessions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using the [`play.api.cache.Cache`](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.cache.CacheAPI) [object](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaCache) if you can come up with a reproducible unique request identifier. Once you have logged your request, you can remove it from the `Cache`.

Comment: do you think the play session ID would be unique considering this would be a read only API with no user authentication.

Comment: [`Request`](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.Request) appears to have an `id` field. You could try using that but you would have to confirm if this is unique to the request. I am not sure.